# anylogic- The right block to simulate the work-in-progress (WIP) in a manufacturing line with push requests

Tags: anylogic

I am still new to AnyLogic. I am trying to resolve a simulation problem with AnyLogic, but I don't know how to do it.
**This is the problem:** There is a single product which will be processed at two machines. Each  machine has its own operator(s). Also, there is before and after the machines some work-in-progress (**WIP**).

How can I modelize this problem with a simple flowchart block? (eg.agent, queue, delay, service and sink)

also, I want to know what block should I use to model the WIP? queue or delay?

what exactly is the difference between these blocks (queue. delay and the service)in terms of duty?

Is it right to use the following blocks to model such a process:
**(source, queue, delay, service, queue1, delay1, service1, sink respectively).**

Many thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Hi Marjan, welcome to SO! Can you specify what WIP means in your case? Is it a place where parts are just waiting, like a buffer before and after process? Or is it a place where actual work is done (pre-/postprocessing)? Is there a fixed time the part has to stay in WIP or just until next station is free? Is order of importance or just plain FIFO?

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks a lot! The three categories of stock are raw materials, work-in-progress (WIP) and finished goods. I mean work in progress or process: a piece of work or product that has been begun but is not finished or ready ( in a manufacturing line). These parts have to stay in a place (eg.boxs) just until next station is free. Order is FIFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Process Flow with WIP

You can model it like this:

[image: Process Flow]

Your WIP is now inside the queues of the two `Service` blocks, *service1* and *service2*. You can for example get the current WIP for the first station by calling `service.queueSize()`.

**Note**: the `Service` block is nothing other than a combination of a `Queue` block, a `Delay` block and some optional resource functionality (`Seize` and `Release`). If you use the `Service` block, normally no additional `Queue`, `Delay`,`Seize` and `Release` is needed, because it already "contains" one of each.
The following two process flows are doing the same functionality, just split up in several modules in the second one. This is sometimes handy or even necessary in some special situations:

[image: Process Flow alternative]

To be completely accurate: the 'Seize'-block again contains a queue on its own which can be also seen by the little queue sign inside the block symbol. So in the second example flow, the 'Queue' block would not be needed. It is just to illustrate the possibilites to split up the functionality of the combined blocks to as many as possible "single-use" blocks.

---

### Additional Ressources

The following materials might help you for your further process modeling in AnyLogic:

- [AnyLogic documentation on Process Modeling Library](https://help.anylogic.com/nav/2_0)
- [Process Modeling Tutorial](https://help.anylogic.com/nav/1_0).
- Go to *Help/Example Models* in AnyLogic and search for models with Process Modelling Library, you'll find lots of good examples.

Comment: Now, if someone does not use the service block,  can they use  queue, seize, delay and release blocks instead? Is it true?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I added this in the answer as well for clarification. Look at the second image with the 2 process flows, they are doing the same.

Comment: Note that actually the Seize block already includes a queue (which is what the block icon tries to show) so a Service block is actually only a Seize -- Delay -- Release sequence; your Queue blocks in your second example flow are superfluous.